# Python - Multithreaded Proxy Tester

Tags: python, multithreading, proxy, urllib2

I'm building a proxy checker using multithreads, specificly a thread pool from:

`from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool`.

The http request is by using urllib2.

What I want to do is for each proxy run 20 requests. If it was 1 threaded it would take too much time. thats where the multithreads power comes to help. So once I set up the proxy I want to run those 20 requests, and manage 2 things. One is to count the exceptions and dump the proxy if too many occurs. 2nd Is to save the average response time and present it later.

I just don't manage to implement the above. But I have implemented it with 1 thread:

```
import socket
import ssl
import time
import urllib
import urllib2
import httplib

proxyList = []

def loadProxysFromFile(fileName):
    global proxyList
    with open(fileName) as f:
        proxyList = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]

def setUrllib2Proxy(proxyAddress):
    proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({
        'http': "http://" + proxyAddress,
        'https': "https://" + proxyAddress
    })
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)

def timingRequest(proxy, url):
    error = False
    setUrllib2Proxy(proxy)

    start = time.time()
    try:
        req = urllib2.Request(url)
        urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=5)     #opening the request (getting a response)

    except (urllib2.URLError, httplib.BadStatusLine, ssl.SSLError, socket.error) as e:
        error = True

    end = time.time()
    timing = end - start
    if error:
        print "Error with proxy " + proxy
        return 0
    else:
        print proxy + " Request to " + url + " took: %s"  %timing + " seconds."
        return timing

# Main
loadProxysFromFile("proxyList.txt")
for proxy in proxyList:
    print "Testing: " + proxy
print "\n"

REQUEST_NUM = 20
ERROR_TOLERANCE_NUM = 3
resultList = []

for proxy in proxyList:
    avgTime = 0
    errorCount = 0
    for x in range(0, REQUEST_NUM):
        result = timingRequest(proxy, 'https://www.google.com')
        if (result == 0):
            errorCount += 1
            if (errorCount >= ERROR_TOLERANCE_NUM):
                break
        else:
            avgTime += result
    if (errorCount < ERROR_TOLERANCE_NUM):
        avgTime = avgTime/(REQUEST_NUM-errorCount)
        resultList.append(proxy + " has an average response time of: %s" %avgTime)

print '\n'
print "Results Summery: "
print "-----------------"
for res in resultList:
    print res
```

Things that must be done are:

for every proxy: wait until all 20 requests are over before changing proxy. Sync somehow the threads when they adding up to calculate the average response time (includes not to take in account the exceptions)

The best solutions I've read so far is using `from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool` and `pool.map(func, iterable)` but I cant figure out how to implement it in my code.